# What's the accurate meaning of "exec &>/var/log/a.log" in a shell script?

Tags: sh

I think this is some kind of io redirect but it looks different to the examples from manual. Normally, we can redirect stdout of the script by following line:

```
exec 1> /var/log/a.log
```

But I saw this line in one of script:

```
exec &> /var/log/a.log
```

What's the meaning of '&' here? Is it both stdout and stderr?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is right.

- `exec >filename` command redirects `stdout` to the designated file. This sends all command output that would normally go to `stdout` to that file.
- `command &> filename` redirects both the `stdout` and the `stderr` of command to filename.

Actually, `command &>file` is another form of `command > file 2>&1` (not available in Bourne Shell prior to version 4, final release, or in the standard shell Debian Almquist shell used in Debian/Ubuntu):

What does the `&` charachter do? Very well explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29):

> In shells derived from csh (the C shell), the syntax instead appends
>   the `&` (ampersand) character to the redirect characters, thus achieving
>   a similar result. The reason for this is to distinguish between a file
>   named '1' and stdout, i.e. `cat file 2>1` vs `cat file 2>&1`. In the
>   first case, stderr is redirected to a file named '1' and in the
>   second, stderr is redirected to stdout.

Read more on I/O redirection here:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_02.html#sect_05_02_01